# ath10k-usb loads, but doesn't create device

Tags: usb, broadcom, firmware

This device doesn't work. I've been reduced to "download firmware from wherever the hell, and randomly switch things about in the (vain) hope that something will work." I've been at this for hours now with no success.

Is there a better, or any way at all to figure out wtf kind of firmware I need? Is there some obscure forum post I missed?

lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 014: ID 13b1:0042 Linksys
```

from dmesg:

```
[ 3772.952172] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 13
[ 3774.220750] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
[ 3774.377846] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=13b1, idProduct=0042
[ 3774.377852] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3774.377855] usb 2-1: Product: USBWLAN
[ 3774.377858] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Qualcomm Atheros
[ 3774.377861] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 12345678
[ 3774.407402] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[ 3774.407631] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[ 3774.428691] usb 2-1: WARNING: ath10k USB support is incomplete, don't expect anything to work!
[ 3774.428724] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath10k_usb
[ 3774.429146] usb 2-1: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-usb-6.bin failed with error -2
[ 3774.429480] usb 2-1: qca9377 hw1.1 target 0x05020001 chip_id 0x00000000 sub 0000:0000
[ 3774.429483] usb 2-1: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[ 3774.430032] usb 2-1: firmware ver  api 5 features ignore-otp crc32 177364e7
[ 3774.475671] usb 2-1: found invalid board magic
[ 3774.475690] usb 2-1: board_file api 1 bmi_id N/A crc32 544289f7
[ 3774.528579] usb 2-1: failed to get board id: -95
```

alternate dmesg, with a different board-2.bin:

```
[16874.710566] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath10k_usb
[16874.718559] usb 2-1: Failed to submit usb control message: -71
[16874.718562] usb 2-1: unable to send the bmi data to the device: -71
[16874.718564] usb 2-1: unable to get target info from device
[16874.718567] usb 2-1: could not get target info (-71)
[16874.718574] usb 2-1: could not probe fw (-71)
```

It seems to be complaining that /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/board-2.bin doesn't contain the correct information.

Or maybe /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-usb-5.bin doesn't, IDK.

I've been all over the internet, and tried several different versions of these things, and sometimes get different error messages. (renaming the stock ubuntu 18.04 'firmware-5.bin' to 'firmware-usb-5.bin' results in a message about "failed to fetch board data for bus-usb..." for instance)

rfkill shows nothing
ip link shows only loopback and my built-in ethernet.
ifconfig and iwconfig the same, the interface for this device doesn't end up getting created.

I've even been so desperate as to consult the enclosed CDROM, which turns out to be identical to the download I got. (Almost. The download contains a "firmware-5.bin" that isn't on the CROM.)

I'm making the assumption here that SOME version of the correct firmware/board-2.bin files will magically make this work. Is that a safe assumption? (even if the "correct" versions of those files don't actually exist anywhere.) And if so, how do I find this mythological correct firmware?

What is the difference between these files?

```
eeprom_qca9377_7_1p1_Robin_clpc_as.bin
eeprom_qca9377_7_1p1_Robin_clpc_ce.bin
eeprom_qca9377_7_1p1_Robin_clpc_fcc.bin
eeprom_qca9377_7_1p1_Robin_clpc_ic.bin
```

I'm given to understand that one (or any?) of these is to be renamed "board-2.bin" but which?

Comment: I assume you are referencing this page; is that correct? https://github.com/erstrom/linux-ath/wiki/Firmware Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Yep, that's the tool/instructions that I've tried.

Comment: I don't *know* any answer, but if you are willing to consider it, I'll propose an educated guess and we can examine the result. Please note the warning in *dmesg*: "WARNING: ath10k USB support is incomplete, don't expect anything to work!"